SQLAlchemy 2.0 обработка ошибки Integrity error
Возник такой вопрос при отлове ошибок именно с Integrity Error
При методах update или insert(create) бывают такие случаи у пользователей, что при создании они столкнулись с ошибкой уникальности их имени или почты.
Ну и конечно, алхимия выдает исключение, что запись с данной почтой есть, и нарушается уникальность. Но проблема в том, что в integrity error входят не только проблемы уникальности, и мне надо быть уверенным, что я обработал именно ошибку уникальности, а не каких-то других проблем. Вот примерный код:
async def update(self, data: dict, **filters) -> Company:
    async with async_session() as session:
        query = (
            update(Company).values(**data).filter_by(**filters).returning(Company)
        )

        try:
            result = await session.execute(query)
            await session.commit()
            return result.scalar_one()

        except exc.NoResultFound:
            raise CompanyNotFoundError 

        except exc.IntegrityError as e:
            logger.error(e)
            await session.rollback()
            raise IntegrityViolationError

И метод создания, к примеру, той же компании:
async def update(self, data: dict, **filters) -> Company:
    async with async_session() as session:
        query = (
            update(Company).values(**data).filter_by(**filters).returning(Company)
        )

        try:
            result = await session.execute(query)
            await session.commit()
            return result.scalar_one()

        except exc.NoResultFound:
            raise CompanyNotFoundError 

        except exc.IntegrityError as e:
            logger.error(e)
            await session.rollback()
            raise IntegrityViolationError

Чем я не доволен? Многим, потому что мне все равно придется на уровне контроллеров и презентабельной части выводить "к сожалению данный пользователь уже существует", а не "ошибка при создании записи, данная запись нарушает целостность базы, тем, что ключ уже существует".

У ошибки IntegrityError есть аттрибут orig - Документация.
Через него можно получить исходную ошибку, которая была поймана SQLAlchemy:
На примере psycopg v3:
from psycopg.errors import UniqueViolation

...
try:
    result = await session.execute(query)
except IntegrityError as e:
    if isinstance(e.orig, UniqueViolation):
        # В самой ошибке есть еще данные о поле, которое ее стригерила
        raise NotUnique()
    raise HTTPException(status_code=500)
...

